# regex lookahead problems in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, negative-lookbehind

I have a list of urls like this:

```
iphone-repair/iphone-4s-repair/iphone-4s-lcd-repair
iphone-repair/iphone-4s-repair/iphone-4s-glass-repair
iphone-repair/iphone-4s-repair/iphone-4s-glass-amp-lcd-replacement
```

I want to rewrite them like this:

```
iphone-repair/iphone-4s-repair/iphone-4s-screen-repair
```

I got it working like this:

```
rewrite ^(.*?)-(glass|glass-.*?lcd|lcd)-.*?(replacement|repair)(.*?)  https://${server_name}$1-screen-repair$5 last;
```

The problem is there are also urls like this:

```
iphone-repair/iphone-4s-repair/iphone-4s-front-glass-amp-lcd-amp-back-glass-replacement
```

on which we do *NOT* want any rewrites to happen.

So have been banging my head against the keyboard trying to understand how to get a lookbehind to abort the ENTIRE match if the word "front" appears.

I tried this

```
^(.*?)-(?<!front-)(glass|glass-.*?lcd|lcd)-.*?(replacement|repair)(.+)?
```

but it does not seem to abort the entire match...

any help really appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this

`(?!.+-front)` Negative Lookahead, asserts that the url does not contain `front`

```
^(?!.+-front)(.*?)-(glass|glass-.*?lcd|lcd)-.*?(replacement|repair)(.*?)
```

[Try demo here](https://regex101.com/r/AYYxkQ/2)

please see the explanation on the link.

Comment: thanks so much!! can you explain what made it work, what is it about the nested capture groups that fixed the problem? Also why did you use a negative lookahead instead of a look behind

Comment: `(?!.+-front)` is a negative look ahead and checks whether a `front` word existed. i use  negative lookahead becuase they support quantifiers but negative lookahead does not.